# How to convert a substring into number?

Tags: jquery, string, if-statement, numbers, compare

I'm newbie at coding with jQuery and i'm trying to take the first letter, which is a number, of a text and transforming it into a number, so I can do math with it. This is what my code currently looks like.

```
jQuery(function(){
   var timeName1 = $(".nome1 .wsite-text").text();
   var timeName2 = $(".nome2 .wsite-text").text();

   var vicNumber1 = timeName.substring(0,1);
   var vicNumber2 = timeName.substring(0,1);

   var vicTime1 = parseInt(vicNumber1);
   var vicTime2 = parseInt(vicNumber2);

if (vicTime1 > vicTime2) {
    $(".nome1 .wsite-text").css("color","green");
    $(".nome2 .wsite-text").css("color","red");
} else {
    $(".nome1 .wsite-text").css("color","red");
    $(".nome2 .wsite-text").css("color","green");
};
});
```

In the first example, the text inside timeName1 is "3 Time 1" and the text inside timeName 2 is "2 Time 2". So, the code should make the timeName1 text be green and the timeName2 be red, as 3 > 2.

I don't know what is wrong with this code, so I ask your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `timeName.substring(0,1);` shouldn't it be `timeName1.substring(0,1);`? The same with `timeName2`?

Comment: There may be white-space you are not accounting for, which trimming the text will help.

Comment: You have assigned both `vicNumber1` and `vicNumber2` to `timeName.substring(0,1)`, so they have the same value.

Comment: the typos should show up as console errors... use your browser console!

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `substring()`, `parseInt()` works on leading numerals and ignores trailing alphabetics.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wwxsx4qq/)**

Try this :

```
var $1 = $(".nome1 .wsite-text");
var $2 = $(".nome2 .wsite-text");

var t1 = parseInt($1.text(), 10);
var t2 = parseInt($2.text(), 10);

$1.css('color', (t1 > t2) ? 'green' : 'red');
$2.css('color', (t1 > t2) ? 'red' : 'green');
```